# Why can't I remove a method with delattr?

Tags: python, python-2.7

There mustn't be an error (according to the [docs of Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#delattr)):

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}


    def set_key(self, key, val):
        self.d[key] = val


    def get_key(self, key):
        return self.d[key]


c = C()
delattr(c, 'set_key')
```

However:

```
AttributeError: set_key
```

I can do delattr on a class object. Can I remove a bound function from an instance?

Comment: The docs mention that not all attributes can be deleted: "The function deletes the named attribute, **provided the object allows it**."

Comment: Because it's an attribute of the class, not the object.

Comment: I don't understand your assertion that it "mustn't be an error". The docs say "provided the object allows it".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is correct. If you use `delattr(C, 'set_key')` you will not see that error ... of course no objects made from C will have set_key available to them any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure why Python (2.7 at least) isn't allowing bound methods to be deleted in this manner.

That said, here is one way to simulate your desired behaviour:

```
def delete_method(obj, method_name):
  def stub(*args, **kwargs):
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (
      obj.__class__.__name__, method_name))
  setattr(obj, method_name, stub)

c = C()
delete_method(c, 'set_key')
c.set_key('the_answer', 42)
```

When run, this gives

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'set_key'
```

Note that this technique isn't universal: for example, you won't be able to use it to remove a method from an instance of the `dict` class.

Answer (score 4):

`set_key` is an attribute of the class, not the instance. `delattr(C, 'set_key')` works as expected.

If you want the function not to be available from only the one instance, you can try `c.set_key = None`.

Comment: But surely that has different semantics to what the OP is trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a method to hide member methods (not deleting them) to pass restricted interface to another place:

```
def safe_interface(obj, enabled):
    "Returns an interface object blocking functions which are not in enabled."

    def assert_name(name):
        if name not in enabled:             
            raise KeyError('No attribute %s.' % name)

    class Caller(object):
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            assert_name(name)
            return getattr(obj, name)


        def __setattr__(self, name, val):
            assert_name(name)
            setattr(obj, name, val)


    c = Caller()

    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class C(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.d = {}


        def set_key(self, key, val):
            self.d[key] = val


        def get_key(self, key):
            return self.d[key]

    c = C()

    d = safe_interface(c, ['set_key'])

    key = 'c'
    val = 'm'
    d.set_key(key, val)
    print c.get_key(key)
    print d.get_key(key) # error, this method is not allowed
```